# Dynamically populate a dropdown box with Jquery and Java

Tags: java, jquery, html

Please bear with me as I am new to jQuery, and JEE and am not a programmer :-)
I have followed a number of tutorials on how to dynamically populate a dropdown box; however I can not get it to work.

I want to select a State and populate the Region drop down based on that selection (each State is made up of Regions).

My issue is with the call to the java and return of values.

So far I have (mashed up from a number of tutorials) the following:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-select-group">
                    <label for="selectState">Select State:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectState">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your State</option>
                        <option>ACT</option>
                        <option>NSW</option>
                        <option>NT</option>
                        <option>QLD</option>
                        <option>SA</option>
                        <option>TAS</option>
                        <option>VIC</option>
                        <option>WA</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-select-group">
                    <label for="selectRegion">Select Region:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectRegion">
                        <option>Please select your State first</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectState').on('change', function() {
    //do something here
    //alert($("#accountName").val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RegionView",
        cache: false,
        data: $(selectState).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);                
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        // Clear options
        $("#selectRegion").find("option").remove();
        // Loop through JSON response
        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
            $('#selectRegion').append($('<option>', { value: value.name }, '</option>'));
        })
    });
});
});
```

JAVA

```
package client;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
* The purpose of this View is to return a list of Regions associated with a selected State.
*/

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import server.MySQLConnection;


@WebServlet("/RegionView")
public class RegionView extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String state = request.getParameter("selectState"); // From bootstrap

    response.getWriter().write("Here " + state);

    MySQLConnection.getConnection();

    List<String> listRegions = MySQLConnection.listGroupRegions(state);

    if (listRegions == null || listRegions.isEmpty()) {
        response.getWriter().write("Please select a State");
    }else{
        response.getWriter().write("State found");
        request.setAttribute("selectRegion", listRegions);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the data that you are getting inside the success callback of the ajax request?

Comment: "success: function(data){ $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data); }" provides - "Here New South WalesState found". "}).done(function(response) { $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(response);  $("#selectRegion").find("option").remove();  $.each(response, function (index, value) {  $('#selectRegion').append($('<option>', { value: value.name }, '</option>'));
         })" does not display anything. Should I be using something else besides "$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(response);" to display the response? I tried "console.log(response);" and nothing appears in the log file.

Comment: You are mixing up two conventions. If you are using sucess callback inside the ajax request, you don't need to chain then function to the promise. Otherwise use then function and remove the success callback. One way or another you will be geeting the data in the response which you should be using next to append inside elements.

Comment: Thanks Ghosh. Unfortunately I don't understand what you just wrote. Are you able to give me some code please?

Comment: Hi Sandip, I am sure if this is what you meant; however I tried this and it did not work: "success: function(data){
       $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
       $("#selectRegion").find("option").remove();
       $.each(response, function (index, value) {
              $('#selectRegion').append($('<option>', { value: value.name }, '</option>'));
             })
      }"

Comment: I have made this change as well; however, still no luck "response.getWriter().write("State found");
         String json = new Gson().toJson(listRegions);
         request.setAttribute("selectRegion", json);"

Answer (score 0):

This code answers my question as it allows me to dynamically populate a dropdown box with Jquery and Java:

Java:

```
@WebServlet("/RegionView")
public class RegionView extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String state = request.getParameter("selectState"); // From bootstrap

MySQLConnection.getConnection();

List<String> listRegions = MySQLConnection.listGroupRegions(state);

if (listRegions == null || listRegions.isEmpty()) {
    response.getWriter().write("Please select a State");
}else{          
    String json = new Gson().toJson(listRegions);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
}
}
```

JSON:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectState').on('change', function() {
//do something here
//alert($("#accountName").val());

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RegionView",
    cache: false,
    data: $(selectState).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);

    }
}).done(function(responseJson) {
    dataType: "json",
    // Clear options
    $("#selectRegion").find("option").remove();
    // Loop through JSON response
    $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
        $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#selectRegion"));
    });
});
});
});
```