# Need to return a json list from java to populate a drop down list in html using json

Tags: java, jquery, html, json

This post is related to [Dynamically populate a dropdown box with Jquery and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915815/dynamically-populate-a-dropdown-box-with-jquery-and-java?noredirect=1#comment82926294_47915815)

Which I have solved and posted the answer to. I now have another issue. This is my first project using json, java and html so a bit of a learning curve.

I use the same code to extract some lists (a list of Regions, a list of Districts); however, a different result/format is returned for the District list. The Region list is correct and returns:

[image]

Which I now successfully use to populate a drop down list. I then select one of the values and use very similar code to retune a list of Districts within the Region selected. This returns:

[image]

Note the square brackets and quotes.

The code I use is:

**HTML:**

```
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-select-group">
                    <label for="selectRegion">Select Region:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectRegion" name="selectRegion">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your State first</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-select-group">
                    <label for="selectDistrict">Select District:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectDistrict" name="selectDistrict">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your State first</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JSON:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectState').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RegionView",
        cache: false,
        data: $(selectState).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
        }
    }).done(function(responseJson) {
        dataType: "json",
        // Clear options
        $("#selectRegion").find("option").remove();
        $('#selectRegion').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Region</option>'));
        $("#selectDistrict").find("option").remove();
        $('#selectDistrict').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Region first</option>'));
        $("#selectGroup").find("option").remove();
        $("#selectSection").find("option").remove();
        $("#selectSubSection").find("option").remove();
        // Loop through JSON response to populate the Region drop down
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
            $('<option>').text(value).appendTo($("#selectRegion"));
        });
    });
});
    $('#selectRegion').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "DistrictView",
            cache: false,
            data: $(selectRegion).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
            }
        }).done(function(responseJson2) {
            dataType: "json",
            // Clear options
            $("#selectDistrict").find("option").remove();
            $('#selectDistrict').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your District</option>'));
            $("#selectGroup").find("option").remove();
            $('#selectGroup').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your District first</option>'));
            $("#selectSection").find("option").remove();
            $("#selectSubSection").find("option").remove();
            // Loop through JSON response to populate the District drop down
            alert("Here1");
            $.each(responseJson2, function(key, value) {
                alert("Here2");
                $('<option>').text(value).appendTo($("#selectDistrict"));
            });
        });
    });

    $('#selectDistrict').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GroupView",
            cache: false,
            data: $(selectDistrict).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
            }
        }).done(function(responseJson) {
            dataType: "json",
            // Clear options
            $("#selectGroup").find("option").remove();
            $('#selectGroup').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Group</option>'));
            $("#selectSection").find("option").remove();
            $('#selectSection').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Group first</option>'));
            $("#selectSubSection").find("option").remove();
            // Loop through JSON response to populate the Group drop down
            $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
                $('<option>').text(value).appendTo($("#selectGroup"));
            });
        });
    });
  });
```

Java for Region (reads a selected State and returns a list of Regions which are populated into the drop down list):

```
    @WebServlet("/RegionView")
    public class RegionView extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String state = request.getParameter("selectState"); // From bootstrap

        MySQLConnection.getConnection();

        List<String> listRegions = MySQLConnection.listGroupRegions(state);

        if (listRegions == null || listRegions.isEmpty()) {
            response.getWriter().write("No Regions in this State.");
        }else{          
            String json = new Gson().toJson(listRegions);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
    }
  }
```

I then select a Region and pass it to this java which returns a list of Districts. The Districts are found however the format returned is not correct and so the next drop down is not populated with this list:

```
    @WebServlet("/DistrictView")
    public class DistrictView extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String[] region = request.getParameterValues("selectRegion"); // From bootstrap
        String region0 = region[0];

        MySQLConnection.getConnection();

        List<String> listDistricts = MySQLConnection.listGroupDistricts(region0);

        if (listDistricts == null || listDistricts.isEmpty()) {
            response.getWriter().write("No Districts in this Region.");
        }else{
            String json = new Gson().toJson(listDistricts);
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
    }
 }
```

I want to return this list to the json and populate the drop down list so I can select a District and return a list of Groups in that District. However; even though I am converting to json it returns the value in square brackets and quotes.

Comment: This line is missing from your districts code response.setContentType("application/json");

Comment: You are marvelous!  Please set as answer and I will accept and vote up.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is missing from your districts code response.setContentType("application/json");